# NS app doesn't reset settings on uninstall and install (Android)

Tags: nativescript

I've got a NS app on Android.

Saved a few app specific settings persistent.

Uninstalled and the app and reinstalled.

All the previously saved settings were there.

This should NOT be the case right - uninstall all settings should be cleared.

This is NS 5.0 - JS+TS.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your application settings are being backed up, you could disable that by setting `allowBackup` to `false` on the application tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
.....
<application android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication" 
             android:allowBackup="false" ....
....
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup